# Puzzle from puzzles

Tags: word, knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle

*I like Puzzling SE! Know why? Because I like <s>stealing from</s> getting inspired by all the top questions on this site!*

> 1. Email message from benefactor (1, 7, 3)
> 2. Order logic puzzle(s) to die for (3, 2)
> 3. A married, genuine circle (6, 7, 2)
> 4. No, it’s not a secret game (3, 4, 7)
> 5. Polish fast food (1, 5)
> 6. Longest possible list beginning with single (7, 1)

The solution is **one word indicating another aspect of PSE I like.**

Comment: *Sidenote*: The mechanism for this puzzle was originally intended to be a part of a huge (by my standards) meta-puzzle I had started creating back in May this year, but I ran out of ideas really quickly, and then summer started and I kinda quit the site for no reason. So I guess this is my four-month-old revival puzzle. Hope it was worth it ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: IMO, this is actually a very nice and clever puzzle!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The clues...

> are, like OP indicated, related to questions from Puzzling SE. Each clue contains words that are part of question titles with a word in common. The numbers indicate the letters from that word that we must pick.
> Here is a link to a [Pastebin with the links](https://pastebin.com/46BBjp3n) so they don't show up on the Linked tab and spoil the puzzle.

- 1. Email message from benefactor (1, 7, 3)

> The word is **MYSTERIOUS**. 
> Letters: **MIS**

- 2. Order logic puzzle(s) to die for (3, 2)

> The word is **VISUAL**.
> Letters: **SI**

- 3. A married, genuine circle (6, 7, 2)

> The word is **LOOKING**.
> Letters: **NGO**

- 4. No, it’s not a secret game (3, 4, 7)

> The word is **POLYNOMIAL**.
> Letters: **LYM**

- 5. Polish fast food (1, 5)

> The word is **PREFIX**.
> Letters: **PI**

- 6. Longest possible list beginning with single (7, 1)

> The word is **SENTENCE**.
> Letters: **CS**

So:

> The hidden phrase is **MISSING OLYMPICS**. So I guess what you like about Puzzling SE is its **LOGO**.

Comment: Yep, that’s the other thing I like, well done! One thing about your answer, though: rot13(lbh fubhyq cebonoyl chg gur yvaxf gb gur chmmyrf fbzrjurer ryfr yvxr n cnfgrova be tbbtyr qbp orpnhfr gurl’er fubjvat hc va gur fvqrone naq ner fcbvyvat gur chmmyr n ovg.) In any, here’s your complementary check mark! :)

Comment: @PilsNot3 Whoops, you're right, I'll edit it!